# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'couchbase.cluster'; 'couchbase' is not a package

Tags: python, sdk, couchbase

I get this error when im trying to import couchbase.cluster.

I've already installed homebrew as well as couchbase via pip following the couchbase sdk python documentation in my computer with is running on macOS.

The code is simply the code shown in the sdk python documentation:

```
from couchbase.cluster import Cluster, ClusterOptions, QueryOptions
from couchbase_core.cluster import PasswordAuthenticator



cluster = Cluster('couchbase://localhost', ClusterOptions(PasswordAuthenticator('username', 'password')))
cb = cluster.bucket('bucket-name')
cb_coll = cb.default_collection()
cb_coll.upsert('u:king_arthur',
               {'name': 'Arthur', 'email': 'kingarthur@couchbase.com', 'interests': ['Holy Grail', 'African Swallows']})
# OperationResult<RC=0x0, Key=u'u:king_arthur', CAS=0xb1da029b0000>

print(cb_coll.get('u:king_arthur').content_as[str])
# {u'interests': [u'Holy Grail', u'African Swallows'], u'name': u'Arthur', u'email': u'kingarthur@couchbase.com'}

## The CREATE PRIMARY INDEX step is only needed the first time you run this script
cluster.query_indexes().create_primary_index('bucket-name')

row_iter = cluster.query('SELECT name FROM bucket-name WHERE $1 IN interests', QueryOptions(positional_parameters=['African Swallows']))
for row in row_iter: print(row)
# {u'name': u'Arthur'}
```

Full error is here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/uriel/Desktop/YiL/couchbase/couchbase.py", line 1, in <module>
    from couchbase.cluster import Cluster, ClusterOptions, QueryOptions
  File "/Users/uriel/Desktop/YiL/couchbase/couchbase.py", line 1, in <module>
    from couchbase.cluster import Cluster, ClusterOptions, QueryOptions
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'couchbase.cluster'; 'couchbase' is not a package
```

Comment: Have you installed Couchbase on your computer? Here's the documentation that might help: https://docs.couchbase.com/python-sdk/2.5/start-using-sdk.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, the directory name was the same as the couchbase module, so python wasn't recognizing it as a module

Comment: I'm getting the same error, which directory name are you referring to?

Comment: the directory's project name

Answer (score 0):

you can install the module with pip command. This would install the required module on your system.

```html
pip install couchbase
```